# How can I create a CSS animation in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, animation, css-animations, opacity

How can I create the CSS animation below in JavaScript? I've looked all over Google, and tried multiple times to create this but I couldn't figure out how to do this.

```css
@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 100;
  }
}
```

To run this, I know I can use what is shown below, but I don't know how to create this animation. Can anyone help?

```js
element.style.animation = "fadeIn 5s linear";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use javascript with `transition` to achieve it

```js
// start frame
const start = {
  opacity: 0
};

// end frame
const end = {
  opacity: 1
};

const element = document.querySelector('span');
Object.assign(element.style, start);
element.style.transition = 'all 5s linear';

requestAnimationFrame(() => {
  Object.assign(element.style, end);
});
```

```html
<span>Lorem Ipsum</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean exactly with "Create in Javascript"? Without using CSS?

If so, you can use a simple interval to update the opacity of the element until it reached 0 or 100. Simple example:

```
let opacity = 0; 
const fadeEl = document.getElementById("fadeInElementIdWithOpacity0");

    const fadeInInterval = setInterval(() => { 
         
        if (opacity < 1) { 
            opacity = opacity + 0.1 
            fadeEl.style.opacity = opacity; 
        } else { 
            clearInterval(fadeInInterval); 
        } 
    }, 200);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first define this function with whatever amount of intervals that you want and then call it with any querySelector

```
function fadeIn(x) { 
            var fade = document.querySelector(x); 
            var opacity = 0; 
            var intervalID = setInterval(function() { 
  
                if (opacity < 1) { 
                    opacity = opacity + 0.1 
                    fade.style.opacity = opacity; 
                } else { 
                    clearInterval(intervalID); 
                } 
            }, 200); 
        }
```

havnig this function in console and running `fadeIn(".-logo")` will fade in the stackoverflow's logo